# Secure scanning of git repositories

Tags: vulnerability-scanners, git

Is it possible to scan files on a 3rd party gitlab installation before they are downloaded ?

In the scenario I'm thinking about colleagues are worried about the potential for malware to be attached to some code coming from a third party hosting their work on their own gitlab server.  They want to transfer repos manually, presumably so they can be scanned on a safe machine before being copied on any kind of networked machine.

Is there a way to do this as part of a scan while getting the files through git ?  WHen I started this question I assumed yes but the more I think about it the more I'm thinking you would have to download the files first and so although the may be 'inert' and relatively sandboxed it would probably inevitable involve more risk ?

Comment: To clarify, the concern is another company is hosting your code in their own git server right?  And you're concerned they may introduce malware into the code you give them to host?

Comment: We are using their code, the management concern is to keep the local network environment bullet proof.  Th instruction is to keep the 2 networks entirely separate.  People are treating that as having to copy code & files manually.  I want to suggest that accessing an git server over https (or even ssh) is not really having the 2 networks touching but I'm trying to make sure I can justify myself.  The only real downside I can see is that we have to download the files before scanning them ?    Not my area but presumably I could look at some kind of jump / bastion server set up ?